# jQuery dynamic search field stopPropagation is not work properly

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to make a responsive dynamic search field . when click on search icon it will show and change the button icon. also it will close when click outside the search field.

CodePen [Here](https://codepen.io/exclutips/pen/ejxpJr)

Buy now it close when click on outside and inside the search field.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  $('.search-button').on('click',function(e){
     e.stopPropagation();
     $('.search-field-wrap').toggle(500);
     $('.search-field-wrap').css("display","flex");
     $('.search-button>.fa').toggleClass("fa-search fa-close");
  });
  
  $(document).click(function(e){
    $(".search-field-wrap").slideUp(300);
    $('.search-button>.fa').toggleClass("fa-search fa-close");
  });
});
```

```css
html {
  margin: 40px auto;
}
.search-field-wrap{
  display:none;
}
.search-wrap{
  display:inline-flex;
}
.search-filed-item{
  display:inline-flex;
}
.btn-search {
   background: #424242;
   border-radius: 0;
   color: #fff;
   border-width: 1px;
   border-style: solid;
   border-color: #1c1c1c;
 }

 .btn-search:active, .btn-search:hover {
   background: #1c1c1c;
   color: #fff;
 }
```

```html
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css'>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css'>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="search-wrap col-sm-4">  
   <button class="search-button btn" type="button"><i class="fa fa-search fa-fw"></i></button>
    <div class="search-field-wrap">
      <input type="text" class="search-filed-item form-control" placeholder="Search for...">
      <button class="search-filed-item btn btn-search" type="button"><i class="fa fa-search fa-fw"></i></button>
    </div>
  </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: You only stop propagation when clicking on the button, not when clicking on the search field.

Comment: then how can I shot slide up when click inside the input field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just check the field property when clicking on the document. It will help you.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  $('.search-button').on('click',function(e){
     e.stopPropagation();
     $('.search-field-wrap').toggle(500);
     $('.search-field-wrap').css("display","flex");
     $('.search-button>.fa').toggleClass("fa-search fa-close");
  });
  
  $(document).click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(".search-field-wrap").slideUp(300);
    if($('.search-field-wrap').css("display") == 'flex'){
      $('.search-button>.fa').toggleClass("fa-search fa-close");
    }
  });

  $(".search-filed-item").click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
  });
});
```

```css
html {
  margin: 40px auto;
}
.search-field-wrap{
  display:none;
}
.search-wrap{
  display:inline-flex;
}
.search-filed-item{
  display:inline-flex;
}
.btn-search {
   background: #424242;
   border-radius: 0;
   color: #fff;
   border-width: 1px;
   border-style: solid;
   border-color: #1c1c1c;
 }

 .btn-search:active, .btn-search:hover {
   background: #1c1c1c;
   color: #fff;
 }
```

```html
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css'>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css'>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="search-wrap col-sm-4">  
   <button class="search-button btn" type="button"><i class="fa fa-search fa-fw"></i></button>
    <div class="search-field-wrap">
      <input type="text" class="search-filed-item form-control" placeholder="Search for...">
      <button class="search-filed-item btn btn-search" type="button"><i class="fa fa-search fa-fw"></i></button>
    </div>
  </div> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a click handler for the input field and search button, so that clicking there doesn't propagate to the document.

Also, clicking outside the search button should always close the search field, not toggle it.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  $('.search-button').on('click',function(e){
     e.stopPropagation();
     $('.search-field-wrap').toggle(500);
     $('.search-field-wrap').css("display","flex");
     $('.search-button>.fa').toggleClass("fa-search fa-close");
  });
  
  $(document).click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(".search-field-wrap").slideUp(300);
    $('.search-button>.fa').removeClass("fa-search").addClass("fa-close");
  });

  $(".search-filed-item").click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
  });
});
```

```css
html {
  margin: 40px auto;
}
.search-field-wrap{
  display:none;
}
.search-wrap{
  display:inline-flex;
}
.search-filed-item{
  display:inline-flex;
}
.btn-search {
   background: #424242;
   border-radius: 0;
   color: #fff;
   border-width: 1px;
   border-style: solid;
   border-color: #1c1c1c;
 }

 .btn-search:active, .btn-search:hover {
   background: #1c1c1c;
   color: #fff;
 }
```

```html
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css'>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css'>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="search-wrap col-sm-4">  
   <button class="search-button btn" type="button"><i class="fa fa-search fa-fw"></i></button>
    <div class="search-field-wrap">
      <input type="text" class="search-filed-item form-control" placeholder="Search for...">
      <button class="search-filed-item btn btn-search" type="button"><i class="fa fa-search fa-fw"></i></button>
    </div>
  </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: yes it solve the problem but when click on document before clicking the button the icon change

Comment: That's what `toggleClass()` does. Why did you use that if you didn't want it to change?

Comment: If you always want it to close, you `removeClass("fa-search").addClass("fa-close")`